# How to check if an item exists on a SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, workflow-lookup

I have a list (List A) which allows people to submit items.
I have another list (List B) with specific individuals on it

I want to create a workflow which when an item is submitted on List A, it will lookup the created by field for the item against the list of names in List B.

If it is a match an email will be sent to both me and the individual who created the item in List A
Then the list item in List A will be deleted.

Any idea if this is possible using a SharePoint 2010 workflow and sharepoint designer 2010
I am using sharepoint server 2016 **NOT** sharepoint online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the sample. It is a 2010 workflow using a condition called If created by. ANd you can select the option "workflow lookup user" to find the user in your list B. The BlackList in data source is your list B. It will lookup the blacklist check if the item is created by user in you list B. Then you can add all actions you need.
Note: Use login Name in the return field.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This works great. I had to modify it slightly so it looks at a different column, because sometimes people submit the items on behalf of others. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

This will help you. Try setting variable (Integer) to the ID of the item matching the item in list B.

http://www.benprins.net/2017/03/13/sharepoint-2013-workflow-check-if-list-item-exists/